# How to configure "authorizenet" module in Drupal 7?

Tags: payment-gateways

I'm trying to configure "[authorizenet](https://www.drupal.org/project/authorizenet)" module for my site.

Following is my requirement and the approach I've taken:

> 1. A site visitor should be able to fill out a form (node create form).
> 2. Once site visitor has filled out all the necessary information
> 3. Then Site visitor should be redirected to authorize.net payment gateway
> 4. where they'll be paying some amount and would be redirected back to my site.

I've used "authorizenet" module and "pay" for above but haven't been able to configure it to match my requirements.

Please note I want to configure this for one content type only.

Can you guys please help me with above?

Thanks.